# SQLite: Multiple choice test generator with conditions and in random order

Tags: sqlite

The title is not very clear I hope to describe my problem better here - feel free to suggest me a better title.

I have a query that returns me a table of team and scores:

```
Team Scores
-------------
Team1    2
Team2    4
Team3    2
Team4    14
Team5    9
Team6    2
Team7    1
Team8    11
Team9    7
```

For each team I'd like to create three additional columns selecting distinct teams within Team1 - Team9 with a score lower that the team considered.
For that purpose we limit ourself here to scores > 2.
This could be a possible result:

```
Team Scores Res1   Res2   Res3
------------------------------
Team2    4  Team1  Team6  Team7
Team4    14 Team9  Team7  Team8
Team5    9  Team6  Team9  Team2
Team8    11 Team1  Team9  Team6
Team9    7  Team2  Team1  Team6
```

Say the table is called T so far I have try this which doesn't work for one additional column:

```
Select T.score, T.team, 
    (Select tea as Res1 
        (Select T.team as tea, T.score as sco 
         from T where sco < T.score order by random()) limit 1)
from T;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with three separate columns while avoiding duplicates would not be easy, so it would be a better idea to use a single column, constructed with [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) from a three-row subquery:

```
SELECT team,
       score,
       (SELECT group_concat(team)
        FROM (SELECT team
              FROM t AS t2
              WHERE t2.score < t.score
              ORDER BY random()
              LIMIT 3)
       ) AS res
FROM t
WHERE res LIKE '%,%,%';
```

(The LIKE filters out rows that do not have three other teams.)

Comment: This almost a perfect answer, beautiful and simple. To improve it one bit would be to have the 3rd column not as string but somehow strip away the " ". Is there any simple way to do that? In any case this answer is considered accepted for me.

Comment: You could wrap another query around that and extract the three values with `instr()` and `substr()`.